# python число на разряды format

Tags: python, format

есть такой код:

```
x = 1234567
'{0:,}'.format(x).replace(',', ' ')

>>> '1 234 567'
```

он прекрасно работает, но, что если у меня будет вот так:

```
x = 1234567
'{0} {1:,}'.format('любая строка, которая содержит запятые', x).replace(',', ' ')
```

как в таком случае мне сделать разбивку числа на разряды, чтобы в {0} не было замены "," на пробел?

Comment: очевидно, что в два шага можно сделать: сперва получаете нужную строчку из числа, потом добавляете её куда хотите.

Comment: @jfs да, но так придется больше редактировать уже готовый код в несколько раз.

Comment: сломанный код не является готовым. Если бы код был "готов", то вопроса бы не было.¶ Если у вас дублирования кода много, то можно отдельный вопрос задать, когда код правильно работать начнёт, в метке [tag:инспекция-кода] если хотите почистись рабочий код.

Comment: @jfs Во-первых без дублей было не обойтись тк это тошнотный телебот в котором было придумано овер9000 правок из-за того, что заказчик не мог продумать тз полностью своей не русской головой. Во-вторых все работает, код готов, это очередная прихоть заказчика. Я сам понимаю о чем ты говоришь, просто хочу поскорее покончить с этим. П.С. междупрочим, поставил плюсик твоему комменту.

Comment: Обязательно нужно, чтобы строка `любая строка, которая содержит запятые` была в формате?